# What would a calculation be for the weight bearing capacity of 6 x 2 studwork?

Tags: load-bearing

I'm building a campus board (a training aid for rock climbing) and my landlord wants to know how someone can be sure a person's body weight can be supported from it.

I'm at a loss on how to give him a calculation for this, I've been very impressed with some of the calculations offered here on other subjects. Can any of you help?

The construction details are - 
Studwork: Structural 6 x 2 CL 25 grade timber. Glued and fixed with 4" 12's with PZ3 head screws.
Left side stud fixed with silicone and 12 no fixings into plasterboard reveal. Right side siliconed, fixed at 3 points into 8mm thick steel column, not compromising structural integrity. Cladded with 12mm WPB hardwood ply.
Campus board: Formed of 4 x 2 CL 25 grade timber. Studwork; cheeks, bottom & face formed of 2 no 12mm WPB hardwood ply. Glued and screwed with 3" 12 PZ3 head screws @ 150 centres.
Mounting: Fixed directly to 6 x 2 studwork with 4" 12's with 18 no PZ3 head screws into back rails, 6 no 8" 12 timberlock decking screws.

Comment: Sorry, but this is outside of my ability to estimate without spending many hours on it. For starters, I'd need a few diagrams because it's really hard to follow exactly how you've constructed it with just text. Also, there are so many different fasteners, glue, etc. that it would be hard to model without FEA software.

Comment: To go along with @Doresoom mentions a 2x6 could support 30 people, at least.  Your weak points and capacity will be dependent on your linkage.

Answer (score 1):

The "deck" is probably fine assuming you used joist hangers, blocking, and is less than 10x10. Attaching it to the structure should be minimum 5\8ths through bolts.

Follow this completely over blown code to eliminate any doubt. It is, however, for stuff you stand on, not climb.

http://www.cityofchicago.org/content/dam/city/depts/bldgs/general/Porch/Porch2011/RevPorch_Guide52611_Secured.pdf

I'd be worried about two things: pulling the whole thing off the wall and pulling off one of the campus boards, both solved with correct sized through bolts. Sounds like its solid as a rock, now you just have to make sure it doesn't come down. I think your landlord may be more concerned that it will fail from not being properly secured then any of the carpentry you built. For this you only need the specs from the fasteners used to secure it. Use 3\4in through bolts and washers where it attaches to the existing studs.

A grade 2, 3\4 bolt has a shear strength of about 10 tons.
https://nucor-fastener.com/Files/PDFs/TechDataSheets/TDS_013_Shear_Strength.pdf 
You should check the pull-out strength of the other fasteners you used and throw those numbers at him, too.

What did you use the silicone for? "fixed at 3 points into 8mm thick steel column" with what? Picture please.

Comment: This may be useful: http://www.homeownershub.com/answers/6-ft-2x6-beam-how-much-downward-pull-can-it-take/